# Will StreamReader and StreamWriter close auto after steam close?

Tags: f#

I have this code:

```
let client = listener.AcceptTcpClient()
let stream = client.GetStream()
let sr = new StreamReader(stream)
let sw = new StreamWriter(stream)
```

How should I close these things after I use them?

If I close client,will stream,sr,sw auto close?Or I need to close them one by one?Or should I use "use" to replace let,then I need not to close them manual?

If I want to use "use" keyword like this:

```
let listener=new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),2000)

let  private loop (client : TcpClient, sr : StreamReader, sw : StreamWriter) = 
async {
    sw.WriteLine("a")
}

let private startLoop () = 
    while true do
        use client = listener.AcceptTcpClient()
        use stream = client.GetStream()
        use sr = new StreamReader(stream)
        use sw = new StreamWriter(stream)
        sw.AutoFlush <- true
        Async.Start(loop (client, sr, sw))

listener.Start()
startLoop ()
```

When client connect,server got error:can't write to closed TextWriter

So when I use "use",the handle will dispose in startLoop function?

In this program,I need to use let,then close client,sr,sw,stream manual?

Thanks

Comment: yes, you would need to `.Dispose` or `.Close` them. Or as you said you can use `use` which will automatically dispose. There are also a bunch of static methods that will do this depending on what you are trying to achive, like `File.ReadAllLines`, etc.

Comment: Thanks,but when I use "use" I got error.I have edit my question

Comment: You should structure your program in a way that the `use` is one the boundary, otherwise as you have observed you will try accessing the resource after it is already disposed. Your other option is yes, closing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StreamReader.Dispose closes the underlying stream, releases the unmanaged resources used by the StreamReader, and optionally releases the managed resources.
That's why theoretically it is enough to use Dispose only on StreamReader 
In your first code (without async) use "use" keyword for all disposable objects even if there is single real unmanaged resource in Stream class.
There are situations when you have one raw stream and you pass it sequentially to many other methods to read peace's of stream using StremReader's.

```
let  readPart stream =
    // note there is no dispose to don't close external stream
    let reader = new StreamReader(stream)
    // read data and return result

use stream = File.Open()
//read first part
let data1 = readPart stream
let data2 = readPart stream
// here stream should be closed
```

In async code you should close streams after usage. You may open stream in infinite loop but don't dispose it there and close StreamWriter after write operation. StreamWriter will dispose will close your stream.

```
sw.WriteLine("a")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged